# setDataSource Error in flutter plugin VideoThumbnail

Tags: flutter, dart

Permission to read External Storage is Granted. I am trying to read the path of files in a folder and if the path contains ".mp4" then make an image thumbnail from the video.

_mediaList the list of paths of all the files in the folder.

sample-path is like storage/emulated/0/StatusSaver/Downloads/469a14c6f26e47968b322b9d08ebe2b0.mp4

```
_mediaList.forEach((element) async {
      if (element.path.contains(".mp4")) {
        print("Video Status");
        await VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData(
          video: element.path,
          imageFormat: ImageFormat.JPEG,
          maxWidth:
              128,
          quality: 25,
        ).then((value) {
          StatusList.insert(0, {
            "type": StatusType.video,
            "path": element.path,
            "thumbnail": value
          });
        });
      }
```

Error is like this

```
I/flutter (18331): PermissionStatus.granted
D/ThumbnailPlugin(18331): buildThumbnailData( format:0, maxh:0, maxw:128, timeMs:0, quality:25 )
W/System.err(18331): java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFEA
W/System.err(18331):    at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever._setDataSource(Native Method)
W/System.err(18331):    at android.media.MediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(MediaMetadataRetriever.java:103)
W/System.err(18331):    at xyz.justsoft.video_thumbnail.VideoThumbnailPlugin.createVideoThumbnail(VideoThumbnailPlugin.java:205)
W/System.err(18331):    at xyz.justsoft.video_thumbnail.VideoThumbnailPlugin.buildThumbnailData(VideoThumbnailPlugin.java:116)
W/System.err(18331):    at xyz.justsoft.video_thumbnail.VideoThumbnailPlugin.access$100(VideoThumbnailPlugin.java:37)
W/System.err(18331):    at xyz.justsoft.video_thumbnail.VideoThumbnailPlugin$1.run(VideoThumbnailPlugin.java:77)
W/System.err(18331):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
W/System.err(18331):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
W/System.err(18331):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)

E/flutter (18331): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method data on channel video_thumbnail)
E/flutter (18331): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
package:flutter/…/services/platform_channel.dart:156
E/flutter (18331): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18331): #1      VideoThumbnail.thumbnailData
package:video_thumbnail/video_thumbnail.dart:67
E/flutter (18331): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18331): #2      FileUtils.readSavedStatusFolder.<anonymous closure>
package:statussaver/model/file_utils.dart:53
E/flutter (18331): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18331):
```

Answer (score 0):

So, The issue was with the path going into the thumbnailData.
I just had to add a "/" at the starting of the path.

As without "/", it was able to read the videos.